# Google App Engine and Google Calendar API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I was wondering if I need the Google java client libraries to access my google calendars from GAE. Are they part of the Google App Engine SDK by default?

Moreover I was not able to find a good example or tutorial which shows how to create, read, update and delete Google calendar events from an Google Cloud Platform app.

Thanks a lot, if you can offer same code examples or links to appropriate and working tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Google Java API client:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/

This library isn't included in App Engine by default, but there are instructions on that page for how to install it.  When you have it set up, here's the guide for using the calendar API:

https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-appengine-sample

Hope this helps!